# Objectify is throwing No Class was registered Error everytime i redeploy the project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Objectify is throwing `"No Class <classname> was found"` error for the entities which i try to retrieve. This happens whenever i deploy a new version to the appengine server. But the class was registered in ofyService and Data is present in datastore.

And i overcome this problem by adding a new entity into the Datastore. Basically i have a web page to retrieve feeds from datastore and another page for inserting feeds into the datastore. whenever i deploy a version it wont retrieve me the feeds,  then i will go and add a new feed and then try retrieving feeds, then all feeds including the old one will get listed.

This seems to be a weird issue. previously it was working fine but i was using some older version of objectify. Currently i am using objectify 5.1

Note: I even tried changing to older version but no use! I have seperated datastore-indexes.xml file does this will be the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make absolutely certain that all registrations occur before you start using Objectify. The safest way to do that is to perform registration in a `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: Yeah moving to servlet context listener worked for me! thanks!